# Oneliner to initiate list of lists in Robot Framework?

Tags: list, multidimensional-array, nested, robotframework

What is the shortest way to initiate nested lists with some values in Robot Framework?

Something like:

```
myList = new List (new List (1, 2 , 3), new List (a, b, c))
```

Comment: Is there anything in the [guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#variables) that is not clear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [Evaluate](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Evaluate) keyword. You can then use normal python syntax to define the list.

```
*** Test Cases ***   
Example
    ${myList}=  Evaluate  [[1,2,3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]

    should be equal  ${myList[1][2]}  c
```